# Suddenly lost data from partitions

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

I have partitioned my hard disk into 6 partition (into ext4 format). Partition 2 (/dev/sda5) had some data. One fine day, I noticed that data is lost. Is there any way to recover the lost data in this case?
Even I cannot figure out how data is lost. No program uses that partition.

Comment: Was it Ubuntu? Was the partition `ext4` ?

Comment: Yes. Partition is ext4